# Selector seleccionado

Tags: javascript

Como hacer cumplir un if si un valor de un `select` es seleccionado

Tengo esto:

```
<select style="width: 120px; position: relative; left: 250px;" class="btn btn-warning btn-clan" onchange="document.getElementById('nick').value = $(this).val()">
<option disabled selected>CLAN</option>
<option value="TYT">TYT</option>
<option value="ZG">ZG</option>
<option value="ZT">ZT</option>
<option value="HERO">HERO</option>
<option value="MGR">MGR</option>
<option value="WARD">WARD</option>
<option value="ACE">ACE</option>
<option value="AG">AG</option>
<option value="sp">SUPERTANKER</option>
</select>
```

y quiero que al elegir el valor "*ZT*" ocurra el `if`.

Comment: puedes publicar el codigo de tu `if`?

Comment: if (this.name.indexOf("hombre") {
  
   mainCtx.save();
               mainCtx.globalAlpha = 1;
                 mainCtx.drawImage(hats.ejected, this.x - this.size, this.y - this.size, 2 * this.size, 2 * this.size);
                 mainCtx.restore();
 
  
  
 }

Answer (score 0):

No puedes acceder al valor directamente. Tienes que hacerlo a través de la propiedad `selectedIndex`. Eso te devuelve la posición del elemento seleccionado de la lista. Para recuperar el valor solo tienes que recuperarlo del select así (por ejemplo): `mySelect.options[mySelect.selectedIndex].value`

Una vez que tengas el valor, ya puedes hacer todo lo que necesites. Te dejo un pequeño ejemplo de como puedes recuperarlo y mostrarlo por la consola:

```js
function valorCambiado(element) {
  console.log(element.options[element.selectedIndex].value);
  }
```

```html
<select style="width: 120px; position: relative; left: 250px;" class="btn btn-warning btn-clan" onchange="valorCambiado(this)">
<option disabled selected>CLAN</option>
<option value="TYT">TYT</option>
<option value="ZG">ZG</option>
<option value="ZT">ZT</option>
<option value="HERO">HERO</option>
<option value="MGR">MGR</option>
<option value="WARD">WARD</option>
<option value="ACE">ACE</option>
<option value="AG">AG</option>
<option value="sp">SUPERTANKER</option>
</select>
```

Espero que te sirva.

Comment: Como se haria esto , ayudame recien aprendo JS

Comment: Te he añadido un ejemplo, pero la respuesta del compañero @wallek876 es completamente válida.

Answer (score 0):

Una opción es utilizar el mismo evento que se genera en `onchange` para realizar la comprobación, pasando el propio valor seleccionado, que se puede obtener de la propiedad `value` del elemento.

```js
    function comprobarCondicion(opcion) {
      this.value = opcion;
      
      if (opcion == 'ZT') {
        console.log('La condicion ZT se cumple');
      }
    }
```

```html
<select style="width: 120px; position: relative; left: 250px;" class="btn btn-warning btn-clan" onchange="comprobarCondicion(this.value)">
    <option disabled selected>CLAN</option>
    <option value="TYT">TYT</option>
    <option value="ZG">ZG</option>
    <option value="ZT">ZT</option>
    <option value="HERO">HERO</option>
    <option value="MGR">MGR</option>
    <option value="WARD">WARD</option>
    <option value="ACE">ACE</option>
    <option value="AG">AG</option>
    <option value="sp">SUPERTANKER</option>
    </select>
```